# Liquibase includeAll doesn't find base path

Tags: gradle, liquibase

while migrating a project from maven to gradle I ran in the following problem.

My file structure looks like this:

[image: Filesystem]

The changelog-master.xml includes the changelog-v1-0.xml, which then should include the directory v1-0 with following line:
  `<includeAll path="src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/v1-0/" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="true" />`.
This works just fine. This: `<includeAll path="/liquibase/changelogs/v1-0/" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="true" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />` doesn't. 
I get following errormessage:

```
Cannot find base path 'src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/changelog-v1-0.xml'
```

with liquibase in version 3.6.2. I also tried the versions 3.6.0, 3.6.1 and 3.5.5. I am using gradle to build my project in version 4.9 and the plugin in version 2.0.1 and also tried 1.2.4 and 2.0.0. I tried all possible combinations of paths and with or without the `relativeToChangelogFile="true"` set and nothing worked so far. I need the path to be relative to the changelog file. I also red various issues in jira, github and stackoverflow and nothing worked so far.

**Why this doesn't work?**

I guess this bug can only be solved by the liquibase community as it seems to be a problem with liquibase itself.

Comment: What are you liquibase settings in application.properties?

Comment: I dont have a application.properties. I think that is a file only used in maven and since i use gradle with the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin) i dont need one. The only property interesting in this case would be the `changeLogFile` and that is set correctly. The problem occures in the changelog-v1-0.xml file

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by adding classpath setting to the definition of the liquibase plugin activity in build.gradle

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
        classpath "$projectDir/src/main/resources/liquibase"
        changeLogFile 'r1.0/r1.0-master.yaml'
        driver 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
        url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName'
        username 'root'
        password 'password'
    }

}}
```

Then, in the master change log file, r1.0-master.yaml, includeAll points to the relative path `included`, where my other changelog files are kept.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: included
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
```